# Oracle Can a Dropped View Be Recovered?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, recovery, flashback

I dropped a view 20 minutes ago.  Can I recover it? If yes, how?

Comment: Restore a backup taken before the view was dropped.

Comment: Pull the correct version from your Cide Repository.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. For example: use flashback query on `DBA_VIEWS`.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> create or replace view v1 as select * from dual;

View created.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2019-11-29 12:30:48

SQL> select count(*) from dba_views where view_name = 'V1';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> select text from dba_views where view_name = 'V1';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select "DUMMY" from dual

SQL> drop view v1;

View dropped.

SQL> select count(*) from dba_views where view_name = 'V1';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> select text from dba_views where view_name = 'V1';

no rows selected

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2019-11-29 12:32:17

SQL> select text from dba_views as of timestamp timestamp'2019-11-29 12:30:48' where view_name = 'V1';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select "DUMMY" from dual
```

This may or may not work, depending on whether you still have the required unto to perform the above flashback query.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: This is very clever. I had not thought of using flashback queries for this use!